# Android best practice for tracking route

Tags: android, gps

I need to be able to track a route the user walk.

Is it just to log the location to the database in OnLocationChanged or is there some better practice for doing this?

Hope someone can help

Regards Jakob

Answer (score 1):

Taking in consideration the possibility of lost of internet connection, yes logging the location to the database is the better practice for me.
`OpenGpsTracker` is doing the same thing. Refer to the [project](https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/) and try to learn from it.
In a side note, the biggest challenge will be trying manage the life of the battery. You can read into this [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) for better practice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will look at the project and learn from that